# Deleting rows after end of consecutive values

Tags: r, for-loop, filtering

I'm working with a dataset where I would like to get rid of the rows for a person once consecutive days end.

This is my starting dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(person = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'),
                 day = c(1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12))

df
  person day
1      A   1
2      A   2
3      A   4
4      B   6
5      B   7
6      B  10
7      B  11
8      B  12
```

And this is my desired result:

```
  person day
1      A   1
2      A   2
4      B   6
5      B   7
```

I've tried using a combination of the `slice`, `cumsum`, and `diff` functions, but I just can't seem to get my desired result. I think a for loop might also work? But, my understanding of for loops is very poor, so I did not explore that route as much.

Any guidance would be very helpful!

Comment: `library(dplyr); df |>  filter(cumsum(coalesce(day - lag(day),0) > 1) == 0, .by = person)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(person) %>% 
  filter(day == min(day)+row_number()-1)
```

or in a single liner:

```
filter(df, day == min(day)+row_number()-1, .by = person)
```

The result:

```
  person day
1      A   1
2      A   2
3      B   6
4      B   7
```

Answer (score 1):

One option using `diff` & `cumall`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(cumall(c(1, diff(day) == 1)), .by = person)

#   person day
# 1      A   1
# 2      A   2
# 3      B   6
# 4      B   7
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply run

```
df %>%
  filter(seq_along(day) + first(day) - 1 == day, .by = person)
```

which gives

```
  person day
1      A   1
2      A   2
3      B   6
4      B   7
```

Answer (score -1):

```
dplyr::slice_head(df,n=2,by=person)
```